# Django class-base generic view to create or update

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I already know how to use one of the class-based generic views CreateView, UpdateView and FormView, but I can't figure out  how to write something clean  in order to create or update an object.
Can somebody help me to subclass one of those views and mixins ?
Thanks

Comment: If you post an example of what you've tried so far, you might get some suggestions how to clean it up. 

I haven't used the class-based generic views yet, but my first suggestion would be to subclass `UpdateView`, and override the `get_object` method.

Comment: I think this is a very good question. I'm looking forward for it to be reopened and answered. Thanks Alasddair for handy tip.